# sed to trim trailing spaces

Tags: sed

Upon trying to delete the trailing spaces in a file

```
sed -i "s/[\s]+$//" 171.ExcelSheetColumnNumber.py
```

[image]

it did not work as expected.

Is any problem with my commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

Sed does not recognize `[\s]+` as a sequence of whitespace characters.

**Solution:**

```
perl -i -lpe "s/\s+$//" 171.ExcelSheetColumnNumber.py
```

or:

```
sed -i -r "s/\s+$//" 171.ExcelSheetColumnNumber.py
```

or:

```
sed -i "s/\s\s*$//" 171.ExcelSheetColumnNumber.py
```

or, as per [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)'s suggestion:

```
sed -i "s/[ \t]*$//" 171.ExcelSheetColumnNumber.py
```

**Explanation:**

- `[\s]` means `\` or `s` to plain sed, and `+` means literal `+`.
- Drop the square brackets as they are unnecessary in this specific case.
- Use a tool that understands the syntax you seem to be familiar with: Perl.
- Alternatively, enable extended regular expressions in sed (still not the same as Perl).

  ```
  -E, -r, --regexp-extended
      use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX -E).
  ```
- Or, modify your expression to only use symbols that are recognized by regular sed: `*` and not `+`.

Comment: ... or you could just use BRE `[ \t]*$` (since replacing zero trailing spaces is a no-op)